90s (or 80s) two-book series about a librarian vs. a vampire over a college girl
I'm not sure on the publication date of the book series I'm trying to identify, but I read this in the 90s and I believe it was fairly recent then.
I'm not entirely sure the series ended at two books, but it did have at least that many.
The first book has a man (a librarian, I think) falling for a woman who is being pursued by a vampire. I believe the setting was a college somewhere. By the end of the book she's been turned, but they manage to kill the vampire.
The second book has them trying to find out more about vampirism and I believe traveling to Europe in search of some vampire society, which they then have to take on. There's some strong concerns that she's falling into the lifestyle and turning against the librarian, but by the end she is on his side and they take down the vampires they sought out (though I forget the details of how that happened).
Any ideas?

Does the book have a modern setting? Any idea if it took place in the US, UK, etc?

Modern setting, set in the US to my recollection for the first book. Then in the second book I believe they're somewhere in Europe.
